# How would I detect a collision between a rigidbody and a static

Tags: unity, collision-detection, 3d, rigidbody, collider

I have an object with a rigid body. How would I go around detecting collisions between this object and any other object with a collider on it?

I know you can enable/disable collision detection (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-detectCollisions.html). Is there an event that gets fired whenever an object collides?

My Rigidbody object:

[image: Bullet]

A typical object that it would collide with:

[image: Plane]

Extra info:
This is Unity 3D, with version 2019.4.8f1o on the Universal Render Pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an event that gets fired whenever an object collides?

[OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html)

```
//Automatically fired when a collision occurs
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {

}
```

This is something you could easily have found with a web search.